# php / mysql: multi column JOIN result into 1 php row

Tags: php, mysql, left-join, outer-join

Please consider this MySQL table structure:

```
table1:
id,name

table2:
table1_id,type, value
```

I am trying to get all names in table1 and all corresponding types and their average values in table2. "type" could be 1 of 3 fixed values:

```
SELECT table1.name ,
AVG(table2.value) as avgvalue,
FROM table1 as table1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 as table2 ON table1.id=table2.table1_id
GROUP BY table1.name,table2.type
```

Result:

```
name | type | avgvalue
-----+------+-------
name1| type1| value1
-----+------+-------
name1| type2| value2
-----+------+-------
name2| type1| value2
-----+------+-------
```

My goal is to list each name and all types/average values in one row in a (HTML-)table, regardless if a type / averagevalue exists or not.

So what I would need is something like:

```
name | type1| type2 |type 3|
-----+------+---------------
name1|value1| value2|      |
-----+------+-------+------+
name2|value2|       |      |
-----+------+-------+------+
```

**My question:**
Should I use SQL or php to modify the results in order to list all types for a particular name?

If SQL, how? Is my LEFT OUTER JOIN even the right way?

If PHP, what would be the best practice there?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following technique for generating the pivot table as

```
select 
t1.name,
max(case when t2.type = 'type1' then t2.value end) as `type1`,
max(case when t2.type = 'type2' then t2.value end) as `type2`,
max(case when t2.type = 'type3' then t2.value end) as `type3`
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2 on t2.table1_id = t1.id
group by t1.name
```

Comment: Dear Abhik, I didn't know about the conditional, this is exactly what I need. Thank you very much!